# Select parsed int, if string was parseable to int

Tags: c#, linq, int

So I have an `IEnumerable<string>` which can contain values that can be parsed as `int`, as well as values that cannot be.

As you know, `Int32.Parse` throws an exception if a string cannot be changed to an int, while `Int32.TryParse` can be used to check and see if the conversion was possible without dealing with the exception.

So I want to use a LINQ query to one-liner parse those strings which can be parsed as int, without throwing an exception along the way. I have a solution, but would like advice from the community about whether this is the best approach.

Here's what I have:

```
int asInt = 0;
var ints = from str in strings
           where Int32.TryParse(str, out asInt)
           select Int32.Parse(str);
```

So as you can see, I'm using `asInt` as a scratch space for the call to `TryParse`, just to determine if `TryParse` would succeed (return bool). Then, in the projection, I'm actually performing the parse. That feels ugly.

Is this the best way to filter the parseable values in one-line using LINQ?

Comment: You can use `asInt` directly as the select value.

Comment: Right; looks like Joe's answer captures that. I actually changed it to my accepted answer since it's more concise than some of the others.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It's hard to do that in query syntax, but it's not too bad in lambda syntax:

```
var ints = strings.Select(str => {
                             int value;
                             bool success = int.TryParse(str, out value);
                             return new { value, success };
                         })
                  .Where(pair => pair.success)
                  .Select(pair => pair.value);
```

Alternatively, you may find it worth writing a method which returns an `int?`:

```
public static int? NullableTryParseInt32(string text)
{
    int value;
    return int.TryParse(text, out value) ? (int?) value : null;
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
var ints = from str in strings
           let nullable = NullableTryParseInt32(str)
           where nullable != null
           select nullable.Value;
```

Comment: Seems like pretty much the same idea though, as the query syntax. Good to see in this form though.

Comment: @byte: The difference is that your version has side-effects in touching another variable... so you couldn't run it in parallel, for example.

Comment: I wish the framework had an      int? int.TryParse(string)  method for such cases

Comment: AH yes, for concurrency I can see how this would be problematic. I'd probably use your lambda syntax in that case.

Comment: @JonSkeet - how to do this when dealing with entities from Entity framework? To avoid the Not a store method exception.

Comment: @dotnetter: Search for similar posts with the error message... I'm sure there are plenty. If you can't find a related post, please post a new question.

Answer (score 20):

It's still two codelines, but you can shorten up your original a little:

```
int asInt = 0;
var ints = from str in strings
           where Int32.TryParse(str, out asInt)
           select asInt;
```

Since the TryParse already runs at the time of the select, the `asInt` variable is populated, so you can use that as your return value - you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: This is not best practise. The moment when asInt is initialized is not predictable since it will happen when this LINQ query gets executed(possibly somewhere else in a different method). So you should not rely on asInt being initialized after this query. Better do it as Jon has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind your coworkers jumping you in the parking lot there is a way to do this in one true line of linq (no semicolons) ....

```
strings.Select<string, Func<int,int?>>(s => (n) => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? (int?)n : (int?)null ).Where(λ => λ(0) != null).Select(λ => λ(0).Value);
```

It isn't practical, but doing this in one statement was far too interesting a challenge to pass up.

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably have this little utility method somewhere (I actually do in my current codebase :-))

```
public static class SafeConvert
{
    public static int? ToInt32(string value) 
    {
        int n;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out n))
            return null;
        return n;
    }
}
```

Then you use this much cleaner LINQ statement:

```
from str in strings
let number = SafeConvert.ToInt32(str)
where number != null
select number.Value;
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree that using the extra variable *feels ugly*.

Based on [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961697/6400526) and **updating to C# 7.0 solutions** one can use the new [`var out` feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/): (*not much shorter but no need for an inner scope or out of query temp variables*)

```
var result = strings.Select(s => new { Success = int.TryParse(s, out var value), value })
                    .Where(pair => pair.Success)
                    .Select(pair => pair.value);
```

and together with named tuples:

```
var result = strings.Select(s => (int.TryParse(s, out var value), value))
                    .Where(pair => pair.Item1)
                    .Select(pair => pair.value);
```

Or if suggesting a method for it for the use in query syntax:

```
public static int? NullableTryParseInt32(string text)
{
    return int.TryParse(text, out var value) ? (int?)value : null;
}
```

---

I'd love to also suggest a query syntax without an extra method for it but as discussed in the following link `out var` is not supported by c# 7.0 and results in the compilation error:

> Out variable and pattern variable declarations are not allowed within a query clause

The link: [Expression variables in query expressions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

---

Through this is a C# 7.0 feature one can get it to work on earlier .NET versions:

- [C# 7 .NET / CLR / Visual Studio version requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42672957/6400526)
- [Does C# 7.0 work for .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482520/6400526)

Comment: Why don't make it shorter? What about `var numbers = values.Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out int value) ? (int?) value : null);`

Comment: @MarcusDock - that is good too. The reason I did not go for that is that the original result is `IEnumerable<int>` and not `IEnumerable<int?>` and in order to do that with your suggestion I'd also need to add `Where(x => x != null) and to convert to `int` instead of `int?`

Comment: @MarcusDock - see that in question itself there is a filtering of all non numeric results

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define an extension method to do this, I'd create a general solution that is simple to use, instead of requiring you to write a new null-on-failure wrapper for each Try function, **and** requires you to filter out null values.

```
public delegate bool TryFunc<in TSource, TResult>(TSource arg, out TResult result);

public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTry<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TryFunc<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach(var s in source) {
        TResult r;
        if (selector(s, out r))
            yield return r;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var ints = strings.SelectTry<string, int>(int.TryParse);
```

It's a little awkward that C# can't infer `SelectTry`'s generic type arguments.

(`TryFunc`'s TResult can't be covariant (i.e. `out TResult`) like [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As Eric Lippert [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207302/771768) out parameters are [actually just ref parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877515/771768) with fancy write-before-read rules.)

Comment: I like creating an extension method here

Answer (score 2):

I'd this is LINQ-to-objects:

```
static int? ParseInt32(string s) {
    int i;
    if(int.TryParse(s,out i)) return i;
    return null;
}
```

Then in the query:

```
let i = ParseInt32(str)
where i != null
select i.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Carl Walsh's answer, I took it one step further to allow parsing of properties:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTry<TSource, TValue, TResult>(
     this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
     Func<TSource, TValue> selector, 
     TryFunc<TValue, TResult> executor)
{
    foreach (TSource s in source)
    {
        TResult r;
        if (executor(selector(s), out r))
            yield return r;
    }
}
```

Here's an example which also can be found in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ECauo):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        IEnumerable<MyClass> myClassItems = new List<MyClass>() {new MyClass("1"), new MyClass("2"), new MyClass("InvalidValue"), new MyClass("3")};
    
        foreach (int integer in myClassItems.SelectTry<MyClass, string, int>(x => x.MyIntegerAsString, int.TryParse))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(integer);
        }
    }
}

public static class LinqUtilities
{
    public delegate bool TryFunc<in TSource, TResult>(TSource arg, out TResult result);

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTry<TSource, TValue, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector, 
        TryFunc<TValue, TResult> executor)
    {
        foreach (TSource s in source)
        {
            TResult r;
            if (executor(selector(s), out r))
                yield return r;
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string integerAsString)
    {
        this.MyIntegerAsString = integerAsString;
    }

     public string MyIntegerAsString{get;set;}
}
```

Output of this program:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use tuples or anonymous classes if you have to use pipeline syntax (e.g. due to your project's style guidelines prohibiting query syntax).

You can do this:

```cs
var ints = strings.Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : default(int?))
                  .Where(n => n.HasValue);
```

If you need an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of an `IEnumerable<int?>`, append `.Select(n => n.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-line Linq expression and fine with allocating a new object on every loop, I'd use the more powerful [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do this with one Linq call

```
var ints = strings.SelectMany(str => {
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out value))
        return new int[] { value };
    return new int[] { };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a (more less easy) true one-liner (using C#7 syntax, without temporary "pair" variable):

```
strings.Select(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out var i) ? (int?)i : null).Where(i => i != null)
```

If you need `int` as return type (instead of `int?`), check out [this full example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TNQGu3):

```
var strings = new string[] { "12", "abc", "1b", "0" };
var ints = strings.Select(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out var i) ? (int?)i : null).Where(i => i != null).Select(i => (int)i);
foreach (var i in ints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * 100);
}
```

Output

```
1200
0
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this little extension method:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWhere<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, (bool, TResult)> whereSelector)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (whereSelector(item) is (true, var result))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557241/7607408) this is easy to pass in a lambda, rather than requiring a method with an out parameter.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. They want to get parsed values in one statement. Also, it's very awkward to pass this type of `whereSelector` and it isn't necessary. There already are other answers that exactly do what is asked here.