# Find comma in a Textbox full of integers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a textbox that should be filled with int of 4 number, something like this [0000, 4444, 5555, 6666]. I need to get where is the comma and then put the 4 numbers in a var. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried String.Split()? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I just discovered it :) thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `String.Split`?

```
string[] allTokens = textBox1.Text.Split(new []{ ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int[] allInts = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(allTokens, int.Parse);
```

If the format can be invalid you can use `int.TryParse`:

```
int num = 0;
int[] allInts = allTokens
    .Where(s => int.TryParse(s, out num))
    .Select(s => num)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You will get int list

```
var numbers = TextBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(str => {
                         int value;
                         bool success = int.TryParse(str, out value);
                         return new { value, success };
                     })
              .Where(pair => pair.success)
              .Select(pair => pair.value).ToList();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961675/linq-select-parsed-int-if-string-was-parseable-to-int)

Comment: nice, I like the lambda, but what happens when there is not an int?

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
var resultArr = tb.split(",");
foreach (elem in resultArr)
{
    int i;
    if (int.tryparse(elem, out i))
        // do something with i
    else
        // that was not an int
}
```

Comment: And the methods' casing?