# Does C# 7.0 work for .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, c#-7.0

I created a project in Visual Studio 2017 RC to check whether I can use new C# 7.0 language features in a .NET Framework 4.5 project. It seems to me that after referencing `System.ValueTuple` NuGet, new tuples are working fine. Is there anything else I should think about, or is this going to work?

After checking `System.ValueTuple` NuGet dependencies, it looks like .NET Framework 4.0 is not supported. Is this the case, or is there some way to make the new language work in this runtime also?

Comment: I think you'll need, at least, .NET 4.6.1, but you might get away with 4.5.

Comment: One thing to check is whether you will need to compile the application via the dotnet build command e.g. from TFS.  We ran into all sorts of problems trying to compile a .net core application targeting v452 of the framework with the language set to c#7 via the dotnet build command and ended up having to set the language to c#6 - fortunately, this didn't require much by way of code refactoring.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Let's go through [the features new in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7):

- Tuples: [The `System.ValueTuple` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) has a version for the `portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp8` profile. That means it is usable on .Net 4.0. (Not sure why dependencies list only .Net 4.5.)

  If you wanted to use tuples on even lower versions of .Net, it should still work, as long as you add [the code for `ValueTuple` and related types](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src) to your project.
- `out` variables, pattern matching, local functions, more expression-bodied members, `throw` expressions, numeric literal syntax improvements: All these features are just syntax sugar, so they don't need any new capabilities from the framework.
- `ref` locals and returns: This feature exposes in C# what the framework supported since the start, so no changes in the framework are needed here either.
- Generalized async return types: To use this feature, you need a type that has the `AsyncMethodBuilder` attribute, which is in [the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/) (along with one such type, `ValueTask<T>`). This package is only supported on .Net 4.5, so for .Net 4.0, you would need to compile [the relevant types](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/src) yourself. (Using `await` on .Net 4.0 also requires `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, but that's nothing new.)

To sum up: All of C# 7.0 should work on .Net 4.5 after installing the required packages and most of it should work on .Net 4.0 too.

Answer (score 30):

Running a C# 7 compiled application on .NET 4.5 should be fine at this moment, but note that running ASP.NET applications that use ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation won't work on .NET 4.5 because the C# 7.0 compiler requires .NET 4.6 to run.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17908:

> The C# 7.0 compiler (2.0 and higher) requires .NET 4.6 to run

The information on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/2.0.1 (about supporting .NET 4.5) seems to be outdated.

Comment: The question is not about running the compiler, but about running the compiled code.

Comment: Also, [the information in that package description is indeed incorrect and it will be fixed in the next version of the package](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/17942).

Comment: If your application uses dynamic compilation (i.e. asp.net hosted app) then it means that you cant host this application on .NET 4.5, but you're correct some applications compiled using the C# 7 compiler will work - I'll update my answer shortly.