# C# 7 local function not working as expected and no errors being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-7.0

I have an Asp.Net MVC App running with framework version .NET 4.5 and I'm using VS2017 pro version. Users can upload attachments including but not limited to:

- Excel
- Word
- PowerPoint
- pdf
- jpeg
- png

So I have a `private` function which is as follows:

```
private string ImageExtension(string path)
{
  string noImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/Template/No-Image-Available-100x100.jpg");
  string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
  switch (fileExtension)
  {
    case ".jpg":
    case ".jpeg":
    case ".gif":
    case ".png":
       return path;
    default:
       return noImagePath;
   }
}
```

As you can see it's very simple and does not do anything fancy. As I'm only using this in one place I thought about making the use of new C# 7 feature of local function. So I've gone ahead and created my main function as follows and added `ImageExtension(string path)` inside it.

```
public void BugInfo(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    string directoryPath = "directory path";

     //save path of 
     string savePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
     string testString = ImageExtension(savePath);

     string ImageExtension(string path)
     {
        string noImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/Template/No-Image-Available-100x100.jpg");
        string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
        switch (fileExtension)
        {
          case ".jpg":
          case ".jpeg":
          case ".gif":
          case ".png":
             return path;
          default:
             return noImagePath;
         }
      }
    }
  //save values to db here
 }
```

With the above code my project builds without any errors. As soon as I hit `F5` or `Ctrl + F5` I get the following error screen

[image]

If I check in the `ErrorList` to see if there are any errors I get none at all as you can see below.

[image]

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please. Do I have to change any settings or need to include any additional DLLs to make use of C# 7 features.

Looking at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488315/3793448)** answer it seems like all of the C# 7 features should work on .NET 4.5

Comment: Try looking in the Output pane/window, select Compilation in the combo box. Perhaps the error message has been recorded there.

Comment: As well as what @xanatos said, there's a dropdown at the top of the error list pane that lets you choose different sources for display there too (build/intellisense).

Comment: @xanatos Thanks, i'll have a look and see if that helps.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've got two dropdowns which one would you like me to change?

Comment: @Downvoter please let me know how I can improve this question?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to update nuget package named "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" to the latest version. Most likely you have version 1.3.2 installed in your project but you need 2.0.1 to use C# 7 features. Alternatively - you can remove this package at all (together with packages that depend on it) - then it will also work, because it will use your installed compiler, but I don't recommend doing that.

As this package description says:

> .Net Compilers package. Referencing this package will cause the
>   project to be built using the specific version of the C# and Visual
>   Basic compilers contained in the package, as opposed to any system
>   installed version.

So that is why it uses C# 6 compiler for you now.