# Obfuscating Nuget package targeting .NET Standard using SmartAssembly works on machine running .NET 4.7.1 but fails on .NET 4.5.2

Tags: obfuscation, smartassembly

My .net 4.5 project is referencing a nuget package (System.ValueTuple 4.3.0, targeting .netstandard).
The code is obfuscated using SmartAssembly 6.10 (I'm aware this version doesn't support .NET Standard).

The program works fine on a machine running .NET 4.7.1.
The program fails on a machine running .NET 4.5.2 when Value Tuple code is reached with:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program
```

I understand why this fails on 4.5.2 but it's unclear why it's working on 4.7.1. If my version of SmartAssembly doesn't support .NET Standard I'd expect to see the exception on both machines, regardless of .NET version.

Needless to say, when SmartAssembly is not used the program works fine on both machines.

Grateful for your thoughts.

Comment: You may need to install something else https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488315/3254405

Comment: @numbtongue Not quite relevant, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the [same question](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/84259/obfuscating-nuget-package-targeting-net-standard-works-on-machine-on-net-4-7-fails-on-4-5/p1?new=1) in the SA Support forum and got an answer which basically says ".NET standard is a weird creature".

Not marking this as the accepted answer obviously, but it's all we've got at the moment.