# Tuples not working in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I have a C# library in Visual Studio 2017, and I'm trying to use a tuple in an interface:

```
IEnumerable<(Guid Id, string name)> GetFoo ();
```

I have added a reference (via NuGet) to `System.ValueTuple`.

Visual Studio and ReSharper both do not detect problems with this line, but when I build I get errors:

```
------ Build started ------ 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets(121,5):
error : Type expected
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets(121,5):
error : Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
declaration
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets(121,5):
error : Identifier expected; 'string' is a keyword
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets(121,5):
error : ; expected
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets(121,5):
error : Method must have a return type
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This suggests that it is not being compiled using C# 7.

I am targetting .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Things I've tried:

- Installing the latest updates to Visual Studio
- Making the project compile using C# 7 explicitly, via Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version
- Adding a reference to `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`

None has had an effect.

---

**Edit:** Not a duplicate of [C# 7 .NET / CLR / Visual Studio version requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672957), as solution there (NuGet package) did not solve issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# 7 .NET / CLR / Visual Studio version requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672957/c-sharp-7-net-clr-visual-studio-version-requirements)

Comment: That's odd. "*Making the project compile using C# 7 explicity, via Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version*" should have been the solution to this issue.

Comment: Looks like some sort of pre-compilation is not happening... but just a wild guess from me.

Comment: Tuples are working. Thousands of developers use them. The issue is why they don't work in your case. BTW you don't need to add anything extra if you target 4.7.1

Comment: If I use `interface moo{ IEnumerable<(Guid Id, string name)> GetFoo (); }` in LinqPad 5 I get no errors. Have you tried creating a new empty Console project containing only an interface declaration?

Comment: Are you targeting `C# latest major version`, `C# latest minor version` or `C# 7.0`?

Comment: Thanks all. I don't think it's a duplicate. I'm not able to target 4.7.1 due to wider environment constraints.

Comment: The same code *does* work in a new project. Nothing about the library it's not working in seems odd. Any ideas what to look for rather than recreating the project from scratch?

Comment: @DavidArno: I get the same problem with all three

Comment: Can you share the csproj file, or is it proprietary?

Comment: Unfortunately it's proprietary, but I think I've found the bit that's the problem (see below)

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but those errors are not coming from a C# 7.0 compiler, but an older compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've worked out the source of the problem.

The project imports:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Workflow.Targets" />`

Which is the source of the errors in the build output. If I import this into a trivial console project with the above code, I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I don't think so. From the build log, it's using `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.targets`, which would is the right path for my version of .Net. I'm currently trying to work out whether I can just remove this include (finding out what `Workflow.Targets` is doing seems somewhat hard!)

Comment: You can remove it but I wonder how that ended up in your console project. If you open it, it's the `targets` file for Windows Workflow. It shouldn't appear inside a console project - it's *not* part of the template. Did you add any libraries or packages that reference WF?

Comment: It's a library rather than a console project. It's part of a very old code-base, so it may be the case that it was needed at some point in the past but not now. I can't think of a reason that it'd be needed. I'll remove it and put it through the continuous integration/regression tests to see whether it's broken anything. Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you create a new console application or library you *shouldn't* see any references to `Workflow.targets` in the `.csproj` file. That's what makes this so strange.