# FormatException on String to Int.ToList Conversion

Tags: c#, exception, split

```
string aresultlist = File.ReadAllLines(data).ToString();
var bresultlist = aresultlist.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
List<int> resultlist = bresultlist.ToList();
```

Can anyone help with the FormatException I keep getting on this block, "It's the datetime Format, take date first exception". It's a string read from a space delimited text file.

Comment: Why did you add `.ToString();` at the first line? How does your data look like?

Comment: I added ToString because the data's  formatted like this:

Comment: Post sample of text.  ReadAllLines() can cause big issues when parsing text files.  You should read one line at a time using StreamReader().  I've been parsing text files for over 40 years and without seeing actual text I can't give good answer.

Comment: `ReadAllLines` returns string array... using `ToString` to a string array may produce unexpected results, i.e. resulting type instead of value.

Comment: It's not word wrapped here but:45  24  56  55  57  19  2
  68  48  67  39  53  26  3
  31  24  25  17  18  24  2
  24  63  35  57  17  19  3
  59  20  06  57  29  22  2
  32  14  08  58  67  17  3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string[]`. If you call `ToString` on such an object you get the `namespace.classname` as a string. So in your case:

> System.String[]

splitting this string results definetely not a number. But in a `string[]` with on entry, namely:

> System.String[]

If your file has only one line with the space delimited numbers, I would suggest to use [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx). It will read the entire content of the file and return it as 1 `string`. This way you can use your code almost as it is.

```
string aresultlist = File.ReadAllText(data);
var bresultlist = aresultlist.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
List<int> resultlist = bresultlist.ToList();
```

EDIT:

As suggested by [Gilad Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6400526/gilad-green) you might have content in the file that cannot be parsed to a number and will throw an exception. To avoid this you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961697/5174469)

Comment: As in Dimtry's answer here too: I'd recommend using `TryParse` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961675/6400526). And if using C# 7.0 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46150189/6400526)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  List<int> resultList = File
    .ReadLines(data)                      // you've got IEnumerable<string>
    .Select(line => line.Split())         // -/- IEnumerable<string[]>
    .Select(ietms => int.Parse(items[0])) // -/- IEnumerable<int> 
    .ToList();                            // finally, it's List<int>
```

I've assumed that it's the *1st* item of the line which should be converted into `int`: `int.Parse(items[0])`, change `0` into the right index if required.

Try avoiding `ReadAllLines` in favor to `ReadLines`: you don't what *all* the file (which can be long) to be read into an array in *one go*

Comment: I'd recommend using `TryParse` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961675/6400526). And if using C# 7.0 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46150189/6400526)

Comment: @Gilad Green: `TryParse` is a *better choice*, but it may be *too complex* for the author of the question (the very reason I've put *two* `Select` one after one)

Comment: I agree :) And that is why I didn't post an answer of my own including it (together with you managing to post before me :) I just added the comment so author can read about it in addition to your good explanatory answer

Comment: This still returns FormatException. Thanks, it's late where I'm at so I'll check on this in a few hours.

Comment: @Mariah Nelson: `FormatException` means that we're trying to parse -`int.Parse(items[0])` - a string that's *not an integer*, say `"bla-bla-bla"`. Could you, please, *share your file* (or peace of it)?