# Cast IEnumerable<string> to IEnumerable<int> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have:

```
IEnumerable<string> c = codigo_incidencia.Split('#');
```

I need to cast "c" to be an `IEnumerable<int>`. I don´t know how to do this cast in C#.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I wouldn't *cast* this, I'd more likely call `.Select()` on the returned value of `.Split()` and parse the string within the `.Select()`.

Comment: That's not a cast but a conversion. Of course this could happen only if your IEnumerable<string> could be converted to an IEnumerable<int>. What is the content of _codigo_incidencia_?

Comment: kudos to @ChristianGollhardt for finding an appropriate duplicate. FGITW who posted answers are not so fast; they should have use close-votes (or even dupehammer), but noooo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shortest way is to using linq `.Select` likewise:

```
var c = codigo_incidencia.Split('#').Select(int.Parse);
```

If you are not sure that the sections are valid ints then you'd want to use a `TryParse` as in: [Select parsed int, if string was parseable to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961675/6400526). And if working with C# 7.0 you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46150189/6400526) of the question:

```
var result = codigo_incidencia.Split('#')
                 .Select(s => new { Success = int.TryParse(s, out var value), value })
                 .Where(pair => pair.Success)
                 .Select(pair => pair.value);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<int> c = codigo_incidencia.Split('#').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this if the strings are always guaranteed to be numbers:

```
IEnumerable<int> c = codigo_incidencia.Split('#').Select(stringValue => int.Parse(stringValue));
```