# The sum of the numbers at the beginning of the line

Tags: linq

I have a file : `site.log`

```
19 www.mysite.org 
300 cod.mysite.org 
100 www.newfile.com
199 py.mysite.org
45 python.mysite.org/als
45 mysite.org/als/4/d
```

I would like to go through all the poems containing the string `mysite.org` and get the number from the beginning of the text and sum all numbers in front of the given text

```
File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(x => x.Contains("mysite.org")).SelectMany(...));
```

Comment: Is there always a number at the beginning?

Comment: @GiladGreen The number will always be but it is not known from how many digits it will consist of

Answer (score 2):

You are close. After the `Where` use `Select` to project only the beginning of the line:

```
var result = File.ReadLines(filePath)
                 .Where(x => x.Contains("mysite.org"))
                 .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split()[0]))
                 .Sum();
```

Notice that the parsing to int might fail of the prefix is not an integer. You can use `TryParse` instead. If you will want so you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46150189/6400526

Answer (score 0):

I `Split` by a space and `TryParse` first value, if success, I take this value, if not, I take 0

```
var result = File.ReadLines("")
                 .Where(x => x.Contains("mysite.org"))
                 .Select(x => {int temp; return int.TryParse(x.Split(' ')[0], out temp) ? temp : 0;})
                 .Sum();;
```