# Comparing String to Integer in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Importing data from a CSV file, I am trying to answer a few questions. When I try to use LINQ to answer the question,

> "What years were there less than 15000 murders?"

I get stuck trying to compare `string` values located in my lists with the `int` `15000`.

I have tried *Parsing* and trying to *convert* to `Int32`, but to no avail. I have also tried changing the `IEnumerable` and `List` types to *integers* and no success either.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
{
    List<string> years = new List<string>();
    List<string> murders = new List<string>();

    while (!sr.EndofStream)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        years.Add(values[0]);
        murders.Add(values[1]);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> yearQuery = 
        from year in years
        where murders < 15000
        select year;

    foreach (string year in yearQuery)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(year + "");
    }
}
```

I see the **compile time error**,

> "Can not apply '<' operand to type String and int"

but I expect the LINQ to see each `year` that `murder` is above `15000`.

Comment: Still a duplicate but I think the right dup would be more like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961675/6400526

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a bit different design: *single* collection (list) or a *custom* classes (*anonymous* in the example below):

```
 var data = File
   .ReadLines(@"c:\csvFile.csv") // we don't have to work with Streams
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // to be on the safe side
   .Skip(1) // if we have a caption to skip
   .Select(line => line.Split(','))
   .Select(items => new {
      year = int.Parse(items[0]),
      murders = int.Parse(items[1]) 
    })
   .ToList();
```

Now we have `data` which is easy to query:

```
 var years = data
   .Where(item => item.murders < 15000)
   .Select(item => item.year)
   .OrderBy(year => year)    // let's sort the years
   .ToArray();

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, years));
```