# Covariance with generic type and expression

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, covariance

I am trying to use covariance in my Program, but when I use `Expression<Func<T>>` in my method as parameter, I get the following error

> Parameter must be input-safe. Invalid variance.
>   The Type parameter T must be invariently valid on `Expression <TDelegate>`

Is there any way to use expresssion as parameter in method along with covariance ?

Example below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var temp = new Temp<People>();
            TestMethod(temp);

        }

        public static void TestMethod(ITemp<Organism> param)
        {

        }
    }

    class Temp<T> : ITemp<T>
        where T : Organism
    {
        public void Print() {}

        public void SecondPrint(Expression<Func<T>> parameter) {}
    }


    class People : Organism {}
    class Animal : Organism {}
    class Organism {}

    interface ITemp<out T> where T : Organism
    {
        void SecondPrint(Expression<Func<T>> parameter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043054/2860133):

> The "out" means "T is only used in output positions". You are using it in an input position

(even if it is the return type of the `Func` delegate). If the compiler allowed that, you could write (in your example):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var temp = new Temp<People>();
    TestMethod(temp);
}

public static void TestMethod(ITemp<Organism> param)
{
    param.SecondPrint(() => new Animal());
}
```

Calling `SecondPrint` on `Temp<People>`, but passing a lambda that returns an `Animal`.

I would remove the variance annotation on `T`:

```
interface ITemp<T> where T : Organism
{
    void SecondPrint(Expression<Func<T>> parameter);
}
```

and make `TestMethod` parametric in `T`:

```
public static void TestMethod<T>(ITemp<T> param) where T : Organism
{
}
```