# How to add different concrete instances (which all inherit a common interface) to a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I'm trying to add a few concrete instances into collection where all the concrete instances inherit from the same interface. But it doesn't compile.

```
// Common interface.
public interface ISearchService<in TSearchOptions> where TSearchOptions : ISearchOptions
{ .. }

// Concrete #1.
public class FooSearchService : ISearchService<FooSearchOptions>
{ .. }

// Concrete #2.
public class BaaSearchService : ISearchService<BaaSearchOptions>
{ .. }
```

So with the above code, both `Foo` and `Baa` both inherit from an `ISearchService<ISearchOptions>` but each one has defined their own specific SearchOptions type.

So then I'm trying this (which doesn't compile) :

```
var searchServices = new List<ISearchService<ISearchOptions>>
{
    new FooSearchService(),
    new BaaSearchService()
};
```

[I've written the full code up on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1UATx).

The idea is that I have a common collection of concrete instances which they all have a common base interface.

I'm pretty sure that I'm failing at this because of some *variance sillyness which I just don't understand.

I thought maybe I'm trying to do too much .. [so I've tried a new .NET Fiddle with something different](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyeTTT) but that also doesn't work.

I just want a mixed bag of a common generic interface.

Comment: I think you mean "implement a common interface". Inheritance is a class/subclass concept (search for "implements" vs "inherits"). It's best to use proper language concepts so not to confuse other readers which may be learning.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `out` instead of `in`:

`out` means `covariant` which means that the argument can change from a class to one of its base classes. Think of method's return type (**output**), if you can take the result of the method as the base class, you can take any of its derived classes.

`in` means `contravariant` which means that the argument can change from a class to a class derived from it. Think of method's parameters (**input**), if your method can accept a derived class, you can pass to a method that wants a base class.

```
public interface ISearchService<out T> where T : ISearchOptions
{  
}
```

**Note**: Thinking of method's input and output is just my strategy to remember when to use `out` and `in`, it's also the way delegate generic type parameters work. Basically, `covariant` and `contravariant` work in the same way for both interface and delegate.

Comment: U R G H :( Your answer worked ... until ... i added the following method to the interface: `Task<SearchResult> SearchAsync(TSearchOptions searchOptions);` FML :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome: `out` means `output`, but you're using it as input which is invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041664/t-must-be-contravariantly-valid

Comment: So there's no way to do this?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: What you're trying to do does not make sense because it will lose type safety as pointed out in the link about. You could workaround this by defining an `ISearchService` interface (but it still loses type safety), see https://dotnetfiddle.net/1vbcC2.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles when you change the code to this:

```
public interface ISearchService<out TSearchOptions> where TSearchOptions : ISearchOptions
{  }
```