# How do I solve the "cannot implicitly convert [type] to [interface]" error when the interface has multiple generic parameters?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> where TResult : class 
                                                where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}

public interface IQuery<TResult> // Doesn't require anything special, just used to guarantee that IQueryHandlers get the right parameters.
{
}
```

It's intended to be used by `IQueryHandlers` which will take in an `IQuery<TResult>` which defines a query that returns an object of type `TResult`. The `IQueryHandler`'s `Handle` method then returns a `TResult`.

I have the interface implemented on a `DataQueryHandlers` class:

```
public class DataQueryHandlers : IQueryHandler<GetDataById, SomeData>
{
    private IDataSource source;

    public DataQueryHandlers(IDataSource source)
    {
        this.source = source
    }

    public SomeData Handle(GetDataById query)
    {
        // Get the data here and return SomeData object
    }
}
```

where `SomeData` is a data entity, and `GetDataById` is an `IQuery<SomeData>`

However, when I try to instantiate a specific instance:

```
private IQueryHandler<IQuery<SomeData>, SomeData> dataQueryHandlers;
private IDataSource source;

source = new DataSource(); // some data provider

dataQueryHandlers = new DataQueryHandlers(datasource); // This line won't compile
```

I get a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `DataQueryHandlers` to
>   `IQueryHandler<IQuery<SomeData>, SomeData>`. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm sure this is a covariant/contravariant related problem, but I fail to see where the mismatch is. Is there a problem with my in/out generic modifiers? Is what I'm trying to do fundamentally incorrect in some way? Am I missing some obvious "[hair on a fish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043054/3691973)" scenario here?

Comment: Try to change  DataQueryHandlers : IQueryHandler<GetDataById, SomeData> to DataQueryHandlers<in TQuery, out TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TResult : class                                               where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>

Comment: @S.Petrosov you should post this as an answer rather than a comment. With a sentence explaining why, I think this addresses the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your derived class to generic one to be able to do it.
Change it to this:

```
public class DataQueryHandlers<in TQuery, out TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TResult : class where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    private IDataSource source;

    public DataQueryHandlers(IDataSource source)
    {
        this.source = source
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        // Get the data here and return TResult object
    }
}
```

More about Generic Classes you can find [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)

Comment: Hrm, I see. But then that requires that DataQueryHandlers now handle *all* TQuery objects, rather than just the specific ones I want to specify. I suspect that's an issue with my overall architecture though.