# The covariant type is not used as a generic constraint for the interface methods, why? (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, generic-constraints, covariant

The problem:

```
interface ICovariant<out R>
{
    // The following statement generates a compiler error
    // because you can use only contravariant or invariant types
    // in generic constraints.
    // void DoSomething<T>() where T : R;
}
```

Why is the generic constraint on methods in this case not allowed.

EDIT:
Lol I found the answer, Generic type "T" in the method is actually an argument (or an input) and hence it is not covariant.

Comment: Rather than it be void DoSomething<T>() where T : R;

It should just be void DoSomething<R>();

Comment: Because `R` is covariant, `ICovariant<string> cs = default; ICovariant<object> co = cs;` is valid, enabling `cs.DoSomething<FileInfo>();` which would violate the constraint.

Comment: no it doesn't answer the question, i am specifically asking why the statement i provided is not allowed

Comment: @DCCoder Nope. In that case, `R` would be a different generic type (which isn't constrained) and you'd get a warning about it having the same name as the other `R`.

Comment: @GameOver it seems that the link 41686d6564 posted accurately answers that question.

Comment: @GameOver _"no it doesn't answer the question"_ Don't just look at the question and decide it's different from yours. Did you read [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043054/8967612)? It basically says what Aluan said in the comment above and you accepted (in a now-deleted comment). The only difference is that Eric's answer uses a traditional method parameter and your code uses a generic type parameter. The rule is the same though. It applies to both.