# Why do C# out generic type parameters violate covariance?

Tags: c#, covariance, out

I'm unclear as to why the following code snippet isn't covarient?

```
  public interface IResourceColl<out T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IResource {

    int Count { get; }

    T this[int index] { get; }

    bool TryGetValue( string SUID, out T obj ); // Error here?
    }
```

> Error 1   Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly
>   valid on 'IResourceColl.TryGetValue(string, out T)'. 'T' is
>   covariant.

My interface only uses the template parameter in output positions.  I could easily refactor this code to something like

```
  public interface IResourceColl<out T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class, IResource {

    int Count { get; }

    T this[int index] { get; }

    T TryGetValue( string SUID ); // return null if not found
    }
```

but I'm trying to understand if my original code actually violates covariance or if this is a compiler or .NET limitation of covariance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/c-sharp-why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism)

Comment: I highly recommend reading Eric Lippert's excellent series describing variance in C#. [Here is the first entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)

Comment: The important thing to note here is that [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) (the parameter modifier) is totally unrelated to [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) (used on a generic type parameter).

Comment: @Jon - that question applies to C# 3.0 and before. The syntax described here is C# 4.0

Comment: It's worth pointing out that C# generics are not templates. If you are coming from a C++ background, C++ templates and C# generics do not behave the same way.

Comment: @Oded: The generic variance syntax is 4.0, but it has nothing to do with the issue here; the `out` parameter (which *is* the issue) is not.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram you're right, sorry.  I didn't mean to confuse the question with incorrect terminology

Comment: @Jon why is it unrelated?  Removing 'out' on the T generic parameter is another way to "fix" the error so the two are obviously related to this error.

Comment: @MerickOWA: My point is that the problem here is trying to have a variant `out` parameter, which cannot work and is not triggered *only* by generic parameter variance (see linked question). In retrospect, "unrelated" was probably not the correct word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is indeed here:

```
bool TryGetValue( string SUID, out T obj ); // Error here?
```

You marked obj as `out` parameter, that still means though that *you are passing in* `obj` so it cannot be covariant, since you both pass in an instance of type `T` as well as return it.

**Edit:**

Eric Lippert says it better than anyone I refer to [his answer to "ref and out parameters in C# and cannot be marked as variant"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877515/329769) and quote him in regards to `out` parameters:

> Should it be legal to make T marked as "out"? Unfortunately no. "out"
>   actually is not different than "ref" behind the scenes. The only
>   difference between "out" and "ref" is that the compiler forbids
>   reading from an out parameter before it is assigned by the callee, and
>   that the compiler requires assignment before the callee returns
>   normally. **Someone who wrote an implementation of this interface in a
>   .NET language other than C# would be able to read from the item before
>   it was initialized, and therefore it could be used as an input. We
>   therefore forbid marking T as "out" in this case**. That's regrettable,
>   but nothing we can do about it; we have to obey the type safety rules
>   of the CLR.

Comment: I might pass in an instance of something other than a T, but C# rules require that I assign something before I can read it, so it'll never cause a problem.

Comment: Ah I see now, it is possible to read the value in other languages, and eric's blog points out cases even in C# where it 'could' break.  That explains why covariance is violated.

Comment: The problem is that so-called `out` parameters really aren't; a real `out` parameter would cause the compiler to generate a struct type for the function's return, which would include the designated return type and all `out` parameters; the caller would then automatically copy the appropriate fields from the struct to `out` parameters, and then regard the remaining field (if any) as the return value.  If `out` parameters were implemented in that way, they could indeed be covariant.

Comment: @MerickOWA You can also understand this without interfaces and generic covariance. Consider C# version 1.2. Make a method `void MyMethod(out Dog dog) { /* method body */}`. Why can't you call this method like so: `Animal a; MyMethod(out a);` The reason is the same. MyMethod might then get in an `Animal` field. Then call a method that sets the same `Animal` field to `new Cat()`. Then say `dog.Bark();`. (This is just an imitation of Jon Skeet's last example, linked in this answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the possible workaround using extension method. Not necessarily convenient from the implementor point of view, but user should be happy:

```
public interface IExample<out T>
{
    T TryGetByName(string name, out bool success);
}

public static class HelperClass
{
    public static bool TryGetByName<T>(this IExample<T> @this, string name, out T child)
    {
        bool success;
        child = @this.TryGetByName(name, out success);
        return success;
    }
}

public interface IAnimal { };

public interface IFish : IAnimal { };

public class XavierTheFish : IFish { };

public class Aquarium : IExample<IFish>
{
    public IFish TryGetByName(string name, out bool success)
    {
        if (name == "Xavier")
        {
            success = true;
            return new XavierTheFish();
        }
        else
        {
            success = false;
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var aquarium = new Aquarium();
        IAnimal child;
        if (aquarium.TryGetByName("Xavier", out child))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It violates covariance because the value provided to output parameters must be of *exactly* the same type as the output parameter declaration.  For instance, assuming `T` was a string, covariance would imply that it would be ok to do

```
var someIResourceColl = new someIResourceCollClass<String>();
Object k;
someIResourceColl.TryGetValue("Foo", out k); // This will break because k is an Object, not a String
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine this little example and you will understand why it is not allowed:

```
public void Test()
{
    string s = "Hello";
    Foo(out s);
}

public void Foo(out string s) //s is passed with "Hello" even if not usable
{
    s = "Bye";
}
```

`out` means that `s` must be definitely assigned before execution leaves the method and conversely you can not use `s` until it is definitely assigned in the method body. This seems to be compatible with *covariance* rules. But nothing stops you from assigning `s` at the call site before calling the method. This value is passed to the method which means that even if it is not *usable* you are effectively passing in a parameter of a defined type to the method which goes against the rules of *covariance* which state that the generic type can only be used as the return type of a method.