# Using Struct as Generic Parameter and casting to the base interface cause the error: must be a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I need to create a collection of ConcreteProviderX instances to execute LINQ operators on it. I prefer to use struct for ConcreteArgumentsX types, but casting to base interface IArguments while creating an array causes the compile-time error: The type 'IArguments' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ICommandProvider' (Code = CS0453). I have an alternative implementation with class instead of struct for ConcreteArgumentsX types, but it causes a run-time System.InvalidCastException (Unable to cast "SetProvider" to "ICommandProvider"). How the error would be solving for the case with struct and for the case with class?

```
namespace ErrorUsingStructForConcreteArgumentsX
{
    interface ICommandProvider<T> where T : struct, IArguments
    {
        void F(string command, out T? arguments);
    }

    class ConcreteProvider1 : ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments1>
    {
        public void F(string command, out ConcreteArguments1? arguments) { arguments = null; /* other code */ }
    }

    class ConcreteProvider2 : ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments2>
    {
        public void F(string command, out ConcreteArguments2? arguments) { arguments = null; /* other code */ }
    }

    interface IArguments { }
    struct ConcreteArguments1 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */ }
    struct ConcreteArguments2 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */ }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments1> provider = new ConcreteProvider1(); // ok

            // compile-time error
            var providers = new ICommandProvider<IArguments>[]
            {
                (ICommandProvider<IArguments>)new ConcreteProvider1(),
                (ICommandProvider<IArguments>)new ConcreteProvider2()
            };
        }
    }
}

namespace AlternativeUsingClassForConcreteArgumentsX
{
    interface ICommandProvider<IArguments>
    {
        void F(string command, out IArguments arguments);
    }

    class ConcreteProvider1 : ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments1>
    {
        public void F(string command, out ConcreteArguments1 arguments) { arguments = null; /* other code */ }
    }

    class ConcreteProvider2 : ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments2>
    {
        public void F(string command, out ConcreteArguments2 arguments) { arguments = null; /* other code */ }
    }

    interface IArguments { }
    class ConcreteArguments1 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */  }
    class ConcreteArguments2 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */ }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments1> provider = new ConcreteProvider1(); // ok

            // runtime error
            var providers = new ICommandProvider<IArguments>[]
            {
                (ICommandProvider<IArguments>)new ConcreteProvider1(),
                (ICommandProvider<IArguments>)new ConcreteProvider2()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an invariant generic declaration, therefore you a getting an errors. `out` parameters doesn't allow you to have a variant declarations. And you should use an exact type declaration, like this `ICommandProvider<ConcreteArguments1> provider = new ConcreteProvider1();`

Comment: Please, have a look at this thread for the explanation and possible workarounds [Why do C# out generic type parameters violate covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913814/why-do-c-sharp-out-generic-type-parameters-violate-covariance)

Comment: please, see my updated answer. I've added code to test. Feel free to ask any question

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for your comment. Could you, please, show how code should look like this? It would be really helpful to us.

Answer (score 2):

`struct` is value type and `IArguments` is reference type. Reference type is `NULLable`, however value type is **not** `NULLable`.
As generic constraints are always "AND", it means that your `T` should satisfy all conditions which written in your `where` statement - `where T : struct, IArguments`.
So this is a reason why you've got an error:

> The type 'IArguments' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ICommandProvider'

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this implementation will be useful:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ICommandProvider<IArguments> provider = new ConcreteProvider1();
    var providers = new ICommandProvider<IArguments>[]
    {
        new ConcreteProvider1(),
        new ConcreteProvider2()
    };
}
```

And other code looks like this:

```
interface ICommandProvider<T> where T : IArguments
{
    void F(string command, T arguments);
}

class ConcreteProvider1 : ICommandProvider<IArguments>
{
    public void F(string command, IArguments arguments)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class ConcreteProvider2 : ICommandProvider<IArguments>
{
    public void F(string command, IArguments arguments)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

interface IArguments { }
class ConcreteArguments1 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */ }
class ConcreteArguments2 : IArguments { /* some value type properties */ }
```

Comment: StepUp Thanks for the error explanation and suggested answer. But I need to save a specific T constraint, ex. for ConcreteProvider**1** it only  needs to be ConcreteArguments**1** (or type that implements some additional interface e.g. **I**ConcreteArguments**1**)

Comment: @E.Makarchuk then your generic will not work as struct `ConcreteArguments1`  is not equal to `ConcreteArguments2`