# Why doesn't covariance work with out parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

The following code doesn't compile:

```
public void CreateStringList(out List<string> newList)
{
    newList = new List<string>();
}

...

IEnumerable<string> myList;
CreateStringList(out myList);
```

The error given is:

> The out parameter type doesn't match the parameter type

My question is... **why doesn't this work?**  `IEnumerable<string>` is covariant with `List<string>`, so the assignment will never violate type-safety.  And you're not allowed to use an `out` parameter before assigning it, so the fact that the previous value of `newList` might not have been a `List<string>` is irrelevant.

Am I missing something?

Comment: duplicate of [Why doesn't 'ref' and 'out' support polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207144/why-doesnt-ref-and-out-support-polymorphism)

Comment: this not working has nothing to do with `out`

Comment: See in particular "Conclusion 4" in Eric's answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877515/94237) to a very similar question ([Why can't ref and out parameters be variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876315/ref-and-out-parameters-in-c-sharp-and-cannot-be-marked-as-variant)):

> The only difference between "out" and "ref" is that the *compiler*
>   forbids reading from an out parameter before it is assigned by the
>   callee, and that the compiler requires assignment before the callee
>   returns normally.

This implies that languages other than C# don't have this restriction, and could use the parameter as an input. Since an `IEnumerable<string>` cannot be a `List<string>`, this is not allowed.

Comment: Just a small reminder: When downvoting, please make a comment so the answer can be improved/corrected.

Comment: Perhaps because Eric's answer explicitly says that, and no implication is necessary: "Someone who wrote an implementation of this interface in a .NET language other than C# would be able to read from the item before it was initialized, and therefore it could be used as an input."