# Can I have an interface parameter, pass by reference?

Tags: c#, interface, pass-by-reference

I have a method with this signature:

```
protected bool MyMethod (ref IMyInterface model) {
    // stuff and things
}
```

I have a model that I'm passing in from this class:

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface {
    // class stuff and things
}
```

I'm trying to pass my model into the method like so:

```
var model = new MyClass():

MyMethod(ref model);
```

However, I get an error about the type not matching the parameter type. If I don't pass by reference, it works fine. Or, if I cast it and pass it like so, it works fine.

```
var tempModel = (IMyInterface)model;

MyMethod(ref tempModel);
```

I'd rather avoid a cast if it's not necessary, but I can't pass without it. I thought if the class implemented the interface, I could pass the model. Is it just not a thing I can do by reference or am I missing something?

Comment: Silly question, but is it `ref` for a reason? The method might actually assign a new value to `model`, not just alter its fields?

Comment: @Blorgbeard It could probably be refactored, yes. It's one of those things I tried and couldn't do, so I was curious if it WAS possible and if not, maybe some insight as to why.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't use implicit typing, and just define your variable as the interface, it will work:

```
IMyInterface model = new MyClass():

MyMethod(ref model);
```

Arguments passed by `ref` must match the type exactly, as they can be reassigned within the method to another type that matches that contract.  In your case, this won't work.  Imagine the following:

```
protected bool MyMethod (ref IMyInterface model) 
{
    // This has to be allowed
    model = new SomeOtherMyInterface();
}

// Now, in your usage:
var model = new MyClass(); // Exactly the same as MyClass model = new MyClass();

MyMethod(ref model); // Won't compile...

// Here, model would be defined as `MyClass` but have been assigned to a `SomeOtherMyInterface`, hence it's invalid...
```

Comment: The interface doesn't have all of the members the class has, so when I declare it as the interface, I can't set the class-specific properties. Good info, though. I didn't want to go into all of that because the question I had was surrounding the ref with an interface param. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Yatrix You can assign to a separate variable, and pass that.  If you're not reassigning, though, there's no reason to pass by ref in the first place...

Answer (score 6):

`ref` cannot take a *subtype* of the requested type (ie. `IMyInterface`) because then the method cannot guarantee the assignment would not violate the caller (ie. it wanted a `MyClass`). As such using `ref` (or `out`) requires the *exact* type.

This is effectively what the error is:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
IMyInterface f = m; // Okay: "m is IMyInterface"

MyMethod(ref f);    // Okay
m = f;              // Illegal: can't guarantee "f is MyClass".
```

C# simply forbids such with `ref`, although with a bit of "help" manually..

```
m = (MyClass)f;     // "Trusting this is okay"
```

---

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877515/2864740 a more in-depth explanation on reasons for the variance rules of the `out` parameter keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with generics like so:

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static void TryDisposeAndClear<T>(ref T obj) where T : IDisposable
    {
        try
        {
            obj.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }

        obj = default(T);
    }
}
```