# Weird behaviour when deconstructing covariant interfaces into ValueTuples with extension methods

Tags: c#, tuples, covariance, variance, valuetuple

This is my covariant interface with one method returning and enumerable which is also covariant (as it always is). Simple.

```
public interface IDataSource<out TData> {
    IAsyncEnumerable<TData> StreamData(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

Now I want to add more data to that enumerable by making use of a `ValueTuple`:

```
public interface IDataSource<out TData> {
    IAsyncEnumerable<(TData data, DateTime timestamp)>> StreamData(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Now I get a compiler error stating that `TData data` must be invariantly valid. I see, `ValueTuple` is not covariant.

---

Alright, then I'll just roll my own very special tuple since I really want to be able to use that nice deconstruction syntax in the `foreach` later on:

```
public interface IDataSource<out TData> {
    IAsyncEnumerable<IDataTuple<TData>> StreamData(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface IDataTuple<out TData> {
    void Deconstruct(out TData data, out DateTime timestamp);
}
```

But the compiler says no, still. This results in the same error, now on `out TData data`.

---

Alright compiler, you, what do you think about this one:

```
public interface IDataSource<out TData> {
    IAsyncEnumerable<IDataTuple<TData>> StreamData(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public interface IDataTuple<out TData> {
    TData Data { get; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; }
}

public static class DataTupleExtensions {
    public static void Deconstruct<TData>(this IDataTuple<TData> tuple, out TData data, out DateTime timestamp) {
        data = tuple.Data;
        timestamp = tuple.Timestamp;
    }
}

public async Task StreamData<TData>(IDataSource<TData> dataSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    await foreach (var (data, timestamp) in dataSource.StreamData(cancellationToken)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This compiles and works like a charm. But why? **What is the difference between declaring the `Deconstruct` as an extension method rather than an interface method here?** Where does covariance stop and invariance begin?

And moreover, **shouldn't `out` parameters be covariantly valid?** I mean, it's literally the same keyword. It would make sense to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876315/ref-and-out-parameters-in-c-sharp-and-cannot-be-marked-as-variant

Comment: @DavidG Interesting that in pure C# `out` parameters could be covariant, but the internals of the CLR and compatibility with other .Net languages make it impossible and theirfore forbidden. That solves the mystery about the `out` parameter at least. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @BrunoZell *Interesting that in pure C# out parameters could be covariant* [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877515) to referenced question shows that `out` parameters could **not** be covariant in pure C# too.