# Argument not assignable due to contravariance

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, covariance, abstraction

I'm trying to write a simple library that can convert between different types. Using .Net Core 3.1.

The purpose of this would be to convert between two classes that inherit from the same base class.

```
public class SharedBaseClass {}

public class DestinationClass : SharedBaseClass {
    public DestinationClass(){}
}

public class InputClass : SharedBaseClass {
    public InputClass(){}
}
```

As such, I have introduced an interface that defines such a converter

```
public interface IConverter<out TU> where TU : SharedBaseClass
{
    public TU Convert(SharedBaseClass input);
}
```

This interface is then used by the below class to perform the conversions

```
public class ConverterExecutor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IConverter<SharedBaseClass>> _converters;
    
    public ConverterExecutor(Dictionary<Type, IConverter<SharedBaseClass>> converters)
    {
        _converters = converters;
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<SharedBaseClass> ConvertMultiple(IEnumerable<SharedBaseClass> classesToConvert)
    {
        var converted = new List<SharedBaseClass>();
        
        foreach(var toConvert in classesToConvert)
        {
            _converters.TryGetValue(toConvert.GetType(), out var converter);
            
            if (converter != null) {
                converted.Add(converter.Convert(toConvert));
                continue;
            }
                              
            converted.Add(toConvert);
        }
        
        return converted;
    }
}
```

Clients would then simply create implementations of the IConverter interface to encapsulate conversion logic. An example for a converter from `InputClass` to `DestinationClass` would is

```
public class DestinationConverter: IConverter<DestinationClass> {
    public DestinationClass Convert(SharedBaseClass input) {
        return new DestinationClass();
    }
}
```

To complete the example, I've added a short main method of how these would be setup

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var executor = new ConverterExecutor(new Dictionary<Type, IConverter<SharedBaseClass>>{
            // various converters for various types added here
            {typeof(InputClass), new DestinationConverter()}
        });
        
        var result = executor.ConvertMultiple(new List<SharedBaseClass>{new InputClass()});
        Console.WriteLine(result.First());
    }
}
```

This all works, however I am bothered by the fact hat the input parameter of the convert method for an implementation of IConverter is dependent on the base class.

```
public DestinationClass Convert(SharedBaseClass input)
```

To fix this, I tried redefining the interface as such:

```
public interface IConverter<out TU, in T> where TU : SharedBaseClass where T: SharedBaseClass
{
    public TU Convert(T input);
}
```

This refactoring works fine across the involved classes and gives me the correct type within each implementation, however I am getting a compile error within the main method as the signature of the DestinationConverter class is not suitable to be added to the dictionary. I suspect this comes from the fact that the `T: SharedBaseClass` parameter has been added as an `in` parameter (contravariant) on the `IConverter` interface, however leaving it as invariant fails in the same way. I suspect if it would be covariant (not possible with an input param) the compiler would allow this. I'm thinking I got my abstractions wrong somewhere along the way, so what would be a suitable solution in this case?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var executor = new ConverterExecutor(new Dictionary<Type, IConverter<SharedBaseClass, SharedBaseClass>>{
            // various converters for various types to be added here
            {typeof(InputClass), new DestinationConverter()}
        });
        
        var result = executor.ConvertMultiple(new List<SharedBaseClass>{new InputClass()});
        Console.WriteLine(result.First());
    }
}
```

Full refactored example that is failing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vuDCiH

Comment: Use pattern matching and forget about all that hell.

Comment: For some thoughts on "in" parameters and variance, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876315/ref-and-out-parameters-in-c-sharp-and-cannot-be-marked-as-variant/2877515#2877515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you can get any converter out of your dictionary, and give it your `SharedBaseClass` instance to convert. Therefore the converters in your dictionary need to be declared as accepting a `SharedBaseClass`.

If your dictionary accepts converters which take a `SharedBaseClass` instance, then all converters which go into it must also be able to take a `SharedBaseClass` instance to convert, as you're technically able to fetch any one of them out of the dictionary, and give it any `SharedBaseClass` instance.

Any way forwards therefore hinges on us being able to get rid of that dictionary containing `IConverter<SharedBaseClass, SharedBaseClass>` instances. One possible approach is:

```
public class ConverterExecutor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<SharedBaseClass, SharedBaseClass>> _converters = new();
    
    public void RegisterConverter<TU, T>(IConverter<TU, T> converter) where TU : SharedBaseClass where T : SharedBaseClass
    {
        _converters[typeof(T)] = x => converter.Convert((T)x);  
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<SharedBaseClass> ConvertMultiple(IEnumerable<SharedBaseClass> classesToConvert)
    {
        var converted = new List<SharedBaseClass>();
        
        foreach(var toConvert in classesToConvert)
        {
            _converters.TryGetValue(toConvert.GetType(), out var converter);
            
            if (converter != null) {
                converted.Add(converter(toConvert));
                continue;
            }
                              
            converted.Add(toConvert);
        }
        
        return converted;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var executor = new ConverterExecutor();
executor.RegisterConverter(new DestinationConverter());
```

[Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4EUKrO).

We've replaced those `IConverter<SharedBaseClass, SharedBaseClass>` instances with delegates which take a `SharedBaseClass` and return a `SharedBaseClass`. Each delegate holds onto a converter, and casts the `SharedBaseClass` instance into the type which the converter is expecting.

Now if you pass the wrong type to a particular converter you get an `InvalidCastException`: the problem hasn't really gone away, but we've moved the check from compile-time to runtime.